# How can I repeatedly call a function by passing result of its previous execution in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a map

```
{
  :key1 {
      :key2 value
  }
}
```

And I have list of keys say

```
[:key1, :key2]
```

I want to recursively call get function on the map for each element in the list and each sucessive call should use result from the previous funciton call.

I tried writing it using for, iterate and reduce-kv functions of clojure but I am not able to achieve.
Any hints or suggestions will be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is `get-in` fitting the bill?

Comment: Thank you... this is what I was looking for... it solves my usecase :)... but I am still curious if we can implement it ourself using other available clojure constructs!

Comment: @ppp456878 the following does what you want with just `reduce` and `get`: `(reduce get {:key1 {:key2 "value"}} [:key1 :key2])` returns `"value"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to achieve it using get-in defined in clojure core - https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in

```
(get-in map [:key1 :key2])
```